# Get name of other file in directory

Tags: java, directory, usb, device

I am trying to get the directory of a USB device on a Linux (Ubuntu specifically) machine. I did some researching and figured the USB device was under the directory `/dev/bus/usb/002/005`, but the file (005) constantly changes every time I un-plug and plug back in the device to `006`, `007`, etc.

In the directory (`/dev/bus/usb/002/`) there are two files `001` and the other file that constantly changes. So basically the main idea: I am trying to get the name of the file besides `001` in the directory `/dev/bus/usb/002/`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward way to solve it:

```
public String GetNameOfOtherFile() {
    String file = "";
    File f = new File("/dev/bus/usb/002/");
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        String[] list = f.list();
        for (String s : list) {
            if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("001")) {
                file = s;
            }
        }
    }

    return file;
}
```